# Custom property in C# with list need to access list for each item only

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a custom property called Questions the code is below.

```
public class Questions
{
    private List<Question> _q = new List<Question>();

    public List<Question> Question
    {
        get { return _q; }
    } 
}

public class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    private List<string> _Options = new List<string>(); 

    public List<string> Option {
      get { return _Options; }
    }

}
```

I then populate the property with the code below

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    Question q = new Question();
    Questions qs = new Questions();
    doc.Load(string.Format(@"questions.xml"));
    XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question");
    foreach (XmlNode node in list)
    {

            q.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText;
            q.Type = node.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText;
            q.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            XmlNodeList options = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question/options");
            foreach (XmlNode option in options)
            {
                q.Option.Add(option.SelectSingleNode("option").InnerText);
            }
            load.Visible = false;
            qa.Visible = true;

            qs.Question.Add(q);
            DisplayQuestion(qs);

    }
```

Now when I try to access it with the code below I do not get the output I expect. And thus this is where I need help. The Sample XML is at the bottom

```
                Label1.Text = q.Question[CurrentQ].Text;
                for (int i = 0; i < q.Question[CurrentQ].Option.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(q.Question[CurrentQ].Option[i]);
                }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<questions>
  <question>
    <num>1</num>
    <type>radio</type>
    <text>Do you like cake?</text>
    <options>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Sometimes</option>
    </options>
    <name>cake</name>
  </question>
  <question>
    <num>2</num>
    <type>dropdown</type>
    <text>Do you like TV?</text>
    <options>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Sometimes</option>
    </options>
    <name>tv</name>
  </question>
  <question>
    <num>3</num>
    <type>checkbox</type>
    <text>What do you like?</text>
    <options>
      <option>Cake</option>
      <option>TV</option>
      <option>Flipper Reruns</option>
    </options>
    <name>flipper</name>
  </question>
</questions>
```

And the output:

What do you like?

Yes

Yes

Cake

Yes

Yes

Cake

Yes

Yes

Cake

Comment: What **is** the output you are expecting?

Comment: What is the output you are currently receiving?

Comment: Output should be  
  
What do you like?  
Cake  
TV  
Flipper Reruns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is fairly simple.
the error is in the piece of code below.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
Question q = new Question();
Questions qs = new Questions();
doc.Load(string.Format(@"questions.xml"));
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question");
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{

        q.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText;
        q.Type = node.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText;
        q.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        XmlNodeList options = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question/options");
        foreach (XmlNode option in options)
        {
            q.Option.Add(option.SelectSingleNode("option").InnerText);
        }
        load.Visible = false;
        qa.Visible = true;

        qs.Question.Add(q);
        DisplayQuestion(qs);

}
```

C# automatically works by reference ( meaning  pointer to an object instead of copying it).
So in the above statement you declare      `Question q = new Question();`   then you fill it and add it to your list and fill it again. this means only one Question is instantiated and therefor the result is all the same.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

Questions qs = new Questions();
doc.Load(string.Format(@"questions.xml"));
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question");
foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
        Question q = new Question(); // <--- Look here

        q.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText;
        q.Type = node.SelectSingleNode("type").InnerText;
        q.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        XmlNodeList options = doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question/options");
        foreach (XmlNode option in options)
        {
            q.Option.Add(option.SelectSingleNode("option").InnerText);
        }
        load.Visible = false;
        qa.Visible = true;

        qs.Question.Add(q);


}
DisplayQuestion(qs); //<-- And here
```

This way everytime a new question gets instantiated and added to the list instead of overwritten. Because in your questionList every entry is only a pointer to the one instance of the question object you have.

Oh and why did i put the `DisplayQuestion(qs);` down there? 
Because you dont want to draw the entire list over and over again do we?

make sure your Displayquestion function lops trough each question and draws the right controls

Kind Regard Roxas
I hope this helps

Comment: This does help, I see the correct question and the correct number of options, however its still showing me the first option for every question.

Comment: @JDRoberson: Please see my answer. I am explaining why this happens.

Comment: Good to go, thanks for your help, I have been scratching my head for hours!

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the option nodes from `doc` instead of the current `node` inside of the loop.

This expression

```cs
doc.SelectNodes("/questions/question/options");
```

yields

```xml
<options>
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
  <option>Sometimes</option>
</options>
<options>
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
  <option>Sometimes</option>
</options>
<options>
  <option>Cake</option>
  <option>TV</option>
  <option>Flipper Reruns</option>
</options>
```

From this list of options groups you always take the first option of every group!

Try this instead

```
node.SelectNodes("options/option");
```

---

Everything put together

```
foreach (XmlNode node in list) {
    Question q = new Question(); // As RoXaS pointed out!
    ...
    XmlNodeList options = node.SelectNodes("options/option");
    foreach (XmlNode option in options) {
        q.Option.Add(option.InnerText);
    }
    ...
    qs.Question.Add(q);
}
```